# Search a field/column in a tabl for a string

Tags: php, mysql

I want to search a column in a MySQL table for a string that is defined by a variable.
How would that syntax look to do this?

How I imagine it in my head:

```
$var = 'this is a string';

$query = 'SEARCH column IN table for ' . $var;
```

If it is found a number will be appended to the string using PHP and `$var` will become:

```
$var = 'this is a string2';
```

How is this done? Thanks

Comment: Are you asking simply how to query a database for a specific value?

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = "this is a string";

$getstringexists = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE column LIKE '$str'", $connection);
$string_exists = mysql_num_rows($getstringexists);

if($string_exists){
   $str .= "$sting_exists";
}
```

Connect to your database in your own way, I always use a variable like $connection at the end of my query that contains my db info.

If the query returns 5 rows it should make the new $str equal to "this is a string5";

Comment: It's generally preferable in MySQL to use LIKE instead of REGEXP to do string comparisons.

Comment: thanks, see I'm still learning too :) but why is that? because of speed or better matching?

Comment: Speed. I only mentioned it because it's counter-intuitive to most developers. They're very powerful in many other languages (JavaScript, Perl, etc.) so naturally developers will want to use REGEXP in MySQL, but MySQL's implementation of REGEXP is particularly poor and should really only be used as a last resort. For instance `column LIKE 'STRING%'` will use an index if available but REGEXP will never use an index (at least as of 5.1, I know devs have been clamoring for improvement). There are a couple of other performance issues as well which you can easily google and find if interested.